# how to fetch access token for google api.Authenticating with OAuth 2.0 in android

Tags: android, authentication, oauth-2.0, google-reader

I am trying to fetch the access token for google account to access google reader data in android 4.0.4. using google api java client 1.8.0 beta.

sample code is showing the error "The method getAccountManager() is undefined for the type GoogleAccountManager".

https://developers.google.com/google-apps/tasks/oauth-and-tasks-on-android

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly this same problem. It seems that installing all the required libraries for the Tasks API demo is quite a mission with new versions and what not being around. One ends up populating the assets folder with "whatever you can" just to get it working. The culprit in this case is `google-api-client-googleapis-extensions-android2-1.4.1-beta.jar`. It seems this version has an `GoogleAccountManager` object that does not support `getAccountManager()`.

The solution in my case was to simply delete `google-api-client-googleapis-extensions-android2-1.4.1-beta.jar` from the assets folder of my project. This made the problem go away. It will complain that this file is referenced by your project, but just go ahead anyway, you probably already have the correct libraries installed at this point anyway. If your project now has error go into properties, the file might still be referenced there. Just remove that reference as well.

EDIT:
After all that it still didn't work although that error went away. Where I am now is here: http://samples.google-api-java-client.googlecode.com/hg/tasks-android-sample/instructions.html I did the hg bit and the entire project seems to rest on my workstation, including all the correct libraries. But now it's giving:

> 06-18 22:09:48.706: E/TasksSample(19971): null
>
> 06-18 22:09:48.706: E/TasksSample(19971): java.io.IOException
>
> 06-18 22:09:48.706: E/TasksSample(19971):     at
>   android.accounts.AccountManager.convertErrorToException(AccountManager.java:1418)
>
> 06-18 22:09:48.706: E/TasksSample(19971):     at
>   android.accounts.AccountManager.access$400(AccountManager.java:134)
>
> 06-18 22:09:48.706: E/TasksSample(19971):     at
>   android.accounts.AccountManager$AmsTask$Response.onError(AccountManager.java:1279)
>
> 06-18 22:09:48.706: E/TasksSample(19971):     at
>   android.accounts.IAccountManagerResponse$Stub.onTransact(IAccountManagerResponse.java:69)
>
> 06-18 22:09:48.706: E/TasksSample(19971):     at
>   android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:288)
>
> 06-18 22:09:48.706: E/TasksSample(19971):     at
>   dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)